# httpd : modules are wrongly searched in a customized ServerRoot

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I start httpd 2.4 on Centos 7 with a customized ServerRoot /a/b/httpd in systemd :

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-d /a/b/httpd"
```

But httpd tries to find modules in $ServerRoot/modules/ :

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of /a/b/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of 
/a/b/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: 
/a/b/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so: cannot open shared object file: Not a directory
```

The 6th line of 00-base.conf is :

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

And modules are here :

```
# rpm -ql httpd |grep compat
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so
#
```

How can i tell httpd to seach for module here ?

Answer (score 0):

Making missing links in $ServerRoot fixes all issues :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct  3 14:25 logs -> /var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Oct  3 14:24 modules -> /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  3 14:27 run -> /run/httpd
```